# (Office 365 online) How to run add-ins when opening file

Tags: office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins, excel-online, scriptlab

I would like to automate code execution when opening the file. It means that I don't want the part "Code" [Code part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy8KK.png), only the part "Run" like this [Run part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xucam.png)
And if it's possible block access to "Code" part.

I've tried to use `Office.onReady(() => {});` to automate code execution when opening the file (doesn't works), also tried `Office.addin.showAsTaskpane();`

The goal is : have the part "Run" when opening file without touching anything (file can be word/excel/powerpoint).
Thanks